# SQL Insert-Select Statement

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6, insert-select

I use Visual Basic 6.0 with SQL Server 2005

Here is my code :

```
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO schedule (sch_name, st_id, sch_note)
            SELECT '" & txtSchedname.Text & "', st_id, '" & txtNote.Text & "'
            FROM scheduletype
            WHERE st_name = '" & cboSchedtype.Text & "'"
```

This is an insert into select statement and works fine. Two inputs directly saved into the [schedule] table and one input coming from [scheduletype] table.

But what if there is no matching records for cboSchedtype.Text?

```
SELECT st_id
FROM scheduletype
WHERE st_name = '" & cboSchedtype.Text & "'"
```

Here's I want to do :

I. Make a 'sub-insert' for the value of cboSchedtype.Text into the [scheduletype] table only if it doesn't exist (before the main insert query does its thing)

II. Otherwise continue normally. (My code successfully does this.)

Comment: I think you want to use [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Comment: Oh BTW I use SQL Server 2005. Merge is a 2008 syntax.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to add a `scheduletype` if it does not exist.

```
insert into scheduletype 
select 'TheScheduleType'
where not exists (select st_name 
                  from scheduletype
                  where st_name = 'TheScheduleType')
```

After you have done that you can use your insert statement against `schedule` because you know that the row will exist.

Comment: Now lets concentrate on your first example particularly on the SELECT statement. What if cboSchedtype.Text has no matching values on the [scheduletype] table?

If this happens I want the query to insert cboSchedtype.Text into the [scheduletype] table.

BTW your query is invalid. Subqueries are not allowed on insert statements. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: @March - Misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ISNULL`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

```
SELECT st_id FROM scheduletype WHERE st_name = ISNULL('" & cboSchedtype.Text & "', subquery)"
```